# Laser powered LEO launch system

Tags: launch-vehicle, laser, beamed-propulsion

Latest research on beam powered propulsion seem to focus on the microwave spectrum as it is easy to catch by the orbital vehicle. However I argue it could be way cheaper to use a solar powered laser array that emits in the infrared spectrum (ex: Nd:YAG) instead of using an expensive [gyrotron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrotron) array.

How wrong am I as I do not have an extensive physics background? How feasible would it be for the orbital vehicle to catch the infrared beam?

Comment: Can you give some references for the "Latest research on beam powered propulsion"?. In particular is this high-thrust power for launching from the ground, or lower thrust systems for changing orbit, etc.?